# Different compile times on Xcode - clang

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang, llvm-clang

When we are archiving our iOS app after cleaning the build folder, total compile time of archive process is **1700-1900 seconds.**

After a few mins, **still the same codes nothing is changed, and there is no other process on CPU**, archiving the same project is cost over **2500 seconds.**

Our project contains both Swift and Objective-C codes. When I look in to the compile logs,
build times for Swift codes are the same on this two build. But on the other hand, **clang processes is different.**
On the first build each Objective-C file compile time is **between 2 and 3 seconds**. But on the second build, **this times is 14-15 seconds.**

Any ideas why clang process different on the same code on different build ?

Comment: Did you notice this only once or is it reproducible and you always have the same results ? Following builds are always slower than the first clean build ?

Comment: Do you import `...-Swift.h` headers in the ObjC code?

Comment: @McNight We are always clean build folder before each archive.  I can’t find any pattern. But mostly first build is faster than others.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk Yes, we have couple of Swift frameworks imported on Objective-C code.

Comment: No, I asked not about importing other frameworks, but about importing `...-Swift.h` generated header inside of the same module. I.e. you have a mixed ObjC + Swift module, and you use Swift APIs of that module inside ObjC code of that module - is there anything like that?

Comment: Yes, we have a few imports like ...-Swift.h

Comment: Could you please comment out usage of those headers and APIs from them and check if the issue is reproducible?